# Android Notifications - replace one notification with another

Tags: java, android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a React Native application where in some circumstances I need to replace a data only notification that has been sent from one client to another.

I understand that with data only messages the client handles the notification. I have read that a notification can be replaced or cancelled if another is received with the same notification ID.

However, what I don't understand is that it seems that the receiving client is responsible from creating the notification ID?

This is the java code that handles the incoming firebase cloud message:

```java
@ReactMethod
    void navigateToExample(String notificationMessage) {
        ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        Resources res = context.getResources();

        // начиная с Android 8, требуются каналы уведомлений
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_ID_0";

            // https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels
            // https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c
            // https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/515-urok-190-notifications-kanaly.html
            // https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("channel description");
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        }

        // Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, the
        // current one should be canceled before generating a new one.
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        activityIntent.putExtra("FromNotification", true);
        PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // make this notification automatically dismissed when the use touches it
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_announcement_black_24dp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_announcement_black_24dp).setTicker("Large text!").setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(notificationMessage).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL).setContentText("Tap to answer or reject the call")
                .setFullScreenIntent(action, true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        int notificationCode = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        manager.notify(notificationCode, notification);
    }
}
```

Once the notification has been created, how can I know the notification ID in the sending client such that I can replace the existing one?

Here is my code that sends notifications:

```js
export const subscribeToPushNotifications = async () => {

  const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
  console.log(fcmToken);

  if (fcmToken) {
    // user has a device token
    const params = {
      notification_channels: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'apns' : 'gcm',
      device: {
        platform: Platform.OS,
        udid: DeviceInfo.getUniqueId(),
      },
      push_token: {
        environment: 'production',
        client_identification_sequence: fcmToken,
      }
    }

    ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(params, function (error, result) {
      // console.log(error); // errors: ["Token is required"]
      // console.log(result);
    });

    receiveFCMs();

  } else {
    // user doesn't have a device token yet
  }
}

export const sendNotification = async (calleeId, callLength, tagUUID) => {

  const callersUserName = await getUserNameFromStorage();

  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    message: callersUserName + '-' + callLength,
    tag: tagUUID,
  });

  const pushParameters = {
    notification_type: 'push',
    user: { ids: [calleeId] }, // recipients.
    environment: 'production', // environment, can be 'production'.
    message: ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.base64Encode(payload)
  };

  ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.events.create(pushParameters, function (error, result) {
  });
}
```

As you can see, my understanding of exactly how this works, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int notificationCode = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

Simply don't create a random notification id, Instead use a constant id like

```
int notificationCode = 5;
```

If you want unique notifications for each client, you can pack notificationid in your data message, from senders side (like using userid as notification id) and use that as notificationid (received from data message), new notifications from same client will automatically be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Pass unique id to `notificationManager` then only you can see multiple notification in system tray

```
val idUnique = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()

notificationManager.notify(idUnique, builder.build())
```